# Are two confocal parabolas always orthogonal?

Tags: conic-sections

I need help regarding this doubt, i took a few examples and it holds true, but is it safe to conclude that two confocal parabolas cut each other orthogonally? Are there any conditions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_conic_sections#Confocal_parabolas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_conic_sections#Confocal_parabolas)

Comment: actually i went through this article but again i just want to confirm because i didn't fully understand that paragraph

Comment: Would two confocal parabolas that do not intersect be of interest to you?

Comment: For them to intersect orthogonally, they do have to share the same axis of symmetry, and face opposite directions.

Comment: Confocal conics are highly related to conformal mapping in complex analysis.  Such as $z=w^2$ and $z=\cosh w$.

Comment: See the optical proofs [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Confocal_conic_sections).